# Problem at rendering layout page inside other templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I have problem with rendering my layout page in other html pages.

It gives me this error:
`home.gohtml:1:11: executing "home.gohtml" at <{{template "base" .}}>: template "base" not defined`

But when I do it without using my layout page and just a simple html rendering it works fine.
also when I print my pages in the code it's getting all of my html pages and rendering them.

I have this directory:

```
.
templates
├── home.gohtml
└── partials
    └── base.layout.gohtml
```

And here is my `base.layout.gohtml`:

```
{{define "base"}}
<html>
<head>
    {{block "css" .}}{{end}}
</head>
<body>

    {{block "content" .}}{{end}}

    {{block "js" .}}{{end}}
</body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

And it's my `home.gohtml`:

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "content"}}
   <p>hey</p>
{{end}}
```

And it is `template.go`:

```
var functions = template.FuncMap{}  


func CreateTemplateCache() (map[string]*template.Template, error) {
    templateCache := map[string]*template.Template{}

    var pages []string
    err := filepath.Walk("./templates", func(path string, info fs.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if !info.IsDir() {
            pages = append(pages, path)
        }
        return err
    })
    if err != nil {
        return  templateCache, err
    }

    for _, page := range pages {
        name := filepath.Base(page)
        templateSet, err := template.New(name).Funcs(functions).ParseFiles(page)
        if err != nil {
           return  templateCache, err
        }
        templateCache[name] = templateSet
    }

    return templateCache, nil
}

func RenderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, templateName string) {
    templateCache, err := CreateTemplateCache()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    template, ok := templateCache[templateName]
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("Something went wrong!")
    }

    buf := new(bytes.Buffer)

    err = template.Execute(buf, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    _, err = buf.WriteTo(w)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Please help me if you can I'm new to go and stuck at this problem.

Comment: It looks like you parsing each file individually, therefore each `*template.Template` object will know only about the contents of the file from which it was parsed. How and why do you expect the separate `*template.Template` objects to know about each other?

Comment: what if I use `template.ParseGlob()` for `*.layout.gohtml` pages? @mkopriva

Comment: That will not match `home.gohtml` and you'll end up with a `*template.Template` object that's the result of parsing *only* the layout file.

Comment: do you know any stackoverflow links or what should I be looking for? i will be thankful

Comment: You can use `ParseFiles`, passing it the full `pages` slice and "unpacking it, i.e. `template.ParseFiles(pages...)` and then use `(*template.Template).ExecuteTemplate` instead of `(*template.Template).Execute`.

Comment: Note also that, unless your app is in development and you're using some live-reload, you should avoid invoking `CreateTemplateCache` every time. In most cases it is enough to parse the files only once and then re-execute them as many times as you need. Otherwise you are adding unnecessary load on your machine.

Comment: yeah I know that I'm just testing now. Thanks for your help. @mkopriva